# Sources for educational Methods used to train kids for Mitzvos

Tags: chinuch-education

In the previous question "[which-mitzvot-require-early-training](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96358/sources-for-which-mitzvot-require-early-training/)" I asked about WHAT are kids are trained for

In this question, I'd like to know what educational methods are prescribed by the Sages, i.g. HOW should we educate the kids. For example, how do I cause my kid to wear Kipah or Tzitzis, how do I educate them to daven, or to love Torah study?

Possible examples are:

- "חֲנֹךְ לַנַּעַר עַל־פִּי דַרְכּוֹ גַּם כִּי־יַזְקִין לֹא־יָסוּר מִמֶּנָּה׃" (Train a lad in the way he ought to go; He will not swerve from it even in old age. [Mish 22,6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Proverbs.22.6?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - *not really sure what it means*, probably to fit the way to kid's character traits.
- "חוֹשֵׂךְ שִׁבְטוֹ שׂוֹנֵא בְנוֹ וְאֹהֲבוֹ שִׁחֲרוֹ מוּסָר׃" (He who spares the rod hates his son, But he who loves him disciplines him early. [Mish 13, 24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Proverbs.13.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - the use of force.

Comment: Do you want specifically Torah / Halacha sources? Otherwise, I can personally vouch for Uncle Moishy and Torah Tots as two very good examples for how it's been done.

Comment: @DanF I'm searching pretty desperately for Rabbinical (esp early) authorities. Nowadays Rabbis are so influenced by extra-Judaism approaches it is hard to tell what their sources are.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? There's an entire chapter in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch dedicated to raising children (https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.165?lang=bi), and it's relatively easy to (mosty) trace back up from there to the Shulchan Aruch/Rambam/Gemara (the Kitzur I have - Frankel edition w/Mishna Berurah - has the sources in the back). But I suspect that's not what you're looking for. If it is, I'll be happy to post that Siman from the Kitzur as an answer.

Comment: @Salmononius2 the Kiztur is very late, and even there I don't see many HOW, only WHAT, like "teach them that and that". Can you please summarize all "how", like " וְאִם לֹא יִוָּסֵר בִּדְבָרִים, יַכֵּהוּ בַּשֵּׁבֶט וְכַדּוֹמֶה," for example.

Answer (score 4):

[Taanit 24a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Taanit.24a.16?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en)

> .רב איקלע לההוא אתרא. גזר תעניתא ולא אתא מיטרא
>   נחית קמיה שליחא דצבורא. אמר משיב הרוח ונשב זיקא אמר מוריד הגשם ואתא מיטרא.
>   אמר ליה מאי עובדך? אמר ליה מיקרי דרדקי אנא ומקרינא לבני עניי כבני עתירי,
>   וכל דלא אפשר ליה לא שקלינא מיניה מידי **ואית לי פירא דכוורי וכל מאן דפשע משחדינא ליה מינייהו ומסדרינן ליה ומפייסינן ליה עד דאתי וקרי**
>
> Rav came to a place (that suffered drought), he declared a fast, and there was no rain. A Shaliach Tzibur came in front of him. He said "bringer of wind" and the wind started to blow. He said "bringer of rain" and rain started. Rav asked him - what do you do for a living? He told him I teach young children. I don't discriminate poor kids from rich kids, whoever is poor, I don't take anything from him, **and I have a pool with small fish, when a child slacks off, I "bribe" him with one, and I help him and I reconcile with him, until he comes back and read.**